# Get min date across two rows in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the below in SQL

[image]

I would like to select the row with the earliest date in either the PR create date or AC create date field. So in this case, I would want these two records.

[image]

I know that I can write

```
Select email, min(PR_create_date) from table 
group by email
```

However, this will only find the minimum date in the PR_create_date column. How can I find the minimum date in either the PR_create_date or AC_create_date columns?

Comment: what do you mean by `minimum date in either the PR_create_date or AC_create_date `

Comment: Correct. It has one or the other per row.

Comment: @saikumarm  Basically, I want to know the earliest date that appears for an email address.  That date can be either the PR_create_date or the AC_create_date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT email,
       MIN(least(pr_create_date, ac_create_date))
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY email
```

Function `least` returns the minimal value of its arguments.

But if one of arguments is `NULL` then the result is `NULL` too. So you are to write some logic to handle nulls, depending on how nulls must be treated in your business logic: for example you can use "special date" in the far past or future to replace nulls as

```
SELECT email,
       MIN( least( ifnull(pr_create_date, DATE '2999-12-31'),
                   ifnull(ac_create_date, DATE '2999-12-31')) )
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY email
```

But in the simplest case when dates are excluding (i.e. in every row exactly one of the dates is null) its enough to just write

```
SELECT email,
       MIN( ifnull(pr_create_date, ac_create_date) )
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY email
```

Comment: Then provide the logic on how to handle null values.

Comment: This seems to be working.  However, it is returning NULL as the earliest date since all records have NULL in one or the other column.  How can I exclude NULL values from this? @diziaq I want to get the next highest value from NULL

Answer (score 2):

One more solution :

```
 select temp.EMAIL, min(temp.PR_AC_CREATE_DATE)
 from
 (
  select EMAIL , min(PR_CREATE_DATE) as PR_AC_CREATE_DATE
  from table
  group by email

  union

  select EMAIL, min(AC_CREATE_DATE)
  from table
  group by email
  ) temp

 group by temp.EMAIL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE function, solution is for generic sql may be run on mysql

```
select email,min(COALESCE(PR_create_date,AC_create_date)) as mindt 
from tab
group by email
```

Comment: he is not asking for the first not null value

Comment: in comment, he put " It has one or the other per row."

Comment: Check the required output, it has only 2 records. Your solution would return  all records from the table.

Comment: @SomnathKadam@shadow This seems to be working just as well as using the simple case in the accepted solution. This is equivalent to the below, no?   SELECT email,
       MIN( ifnull(pr_create_date, ac_create_date) )
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY email

Answer (score 0):

You can try a more robust solution like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY pr_create_date DESC,ac_create_date DESC LIMIT 5);
```

Order by: specify columns and ordering rule (ascending ASC(default) / descending DESC)

Limit: number of records you want. This will give the top 5 latest records. 
Try it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select email,
       Case When PR_create_date < AC_create_date Then PR_create_date
            When AC_create_date < PR_create_date Then AC_create_date             
            End As TheMin
From   YourTableNameHere
Group By email
```

Comment: If you compare null with a value, then the result will also be null.

Comment: @Shadow: Yes I am completely agree with you. Can you provide solution in this case? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is an accepted answer that takes care of this.